PostGIS: Left Join (ST_intersects) lead to multiple counts (not distinct) in aggregate function
I have a query with 2 left joints (ON ST_Within, ON ST_Intersects).The second left join (ST_Intersects) in the example below causes multiple counts of the point_table in the aggregate function (SUM).
SELECT 
    polygon_table_1.polygon_table_1_id,
    SUM(COALESCE(point_table.field_1,0) + COALESCE(point_table.field_2,0)) as sum_field_1_2
array_agg(DISTINCT polygon_table_2.field) as in_polygon_field,  
FROM 
    polygon_table_1
LEFT JOIN 
    point_table ON ST_Within(point_table.geom, polygon_table_1.geom)
LEFT JOIN 
    polygon_table_2 ON ST_Intersects(polygon_table_1.geom, polygon_table_2.geom)
GROUP BY polygon_table_1.polygon_table_1_id;

However I want to sum up the field values from the point table only once for each point, so that the left join produces only distinct values.
